# Wrapfigure not wraping around caption

Tags: captions, wrapfigure

I am kinda new to tex and I am confussed that wrapfigure is not wraping around caption properly. Here is my text :

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \vspace{-20pt}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{kamdomesta.png}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{-20pt}
  \caption{RegisterActivity}
  \vspace{-10pt}
\end{wrapfigure}
\subsection*{KamDoMesta}
Aplikácia poskytuje používateľom prehľad prebiehajúcich filmových predstavení, výstav, prednášok a pod. vo zvolenom meste v daný deň. Za výhody považujem jednoduché používateľské rozhranie, ktoré tvorí v hlavnej aktivite jeden ListView využívajúci knižnicu StickyHeader, ktorá pomáha rozdeliť záznamy do kategórií. Nevýhod je na druhej strane oveľa viac. Chýba vyhľadávanie podľa zadanej ulice, alebo mesta. V aplikácií sa síce dá zvoliť mesto, ale ich zoznam je celkom priemerný a obsahuje len zopár vybraných miest, dokonca pri spustení aplikácie sa stále zobrazujú výsledky pre mesto Košice. Tak isto chýbajú možnosti pre používateľom pre hodnotenie udalosti, resp. komentovanie, pričom webová verzia aplikácie ponúka pridávanie komentárov pomocou pluginov spoločnosti Facebook, ich zahrnutie do aplikácie by nebolo vôbec náročné.
```

This results into this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlBFD.jpg

I don't know what is wrong, this same code works in other parts of document

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: well this might be kinda big i have uploaded it to git https://github.com/lupajz/bc/blob/master/doc/praca.tex there is the docclass and so https://github.com/lupajz/bc/blob/master/doc/kap2.tex the part that messes up my stuff

Comment: No, just post the minimal text etc. in your question (the editor on this platform which you have alread uses to enter your question)

Comment: You have to specify the number of lines like `\begin{wrapfigure}[16]{r}{0.5\textwidth}` Note that you need `16` lines.

Comment: yea :) solved it myself but thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the number of narrow lines like

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[16]{r}{0.5\textwidth}
```

From your picture, it seems you need 16 lines that are narrow. Also you may need some over hang, since your text did not hyphenate for me.

Code:

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{wrapfigure}[16]{r}[10pt]{0.5\textwidth}     %% remove [10pt] if not needed - over hang
  \vspace{-20pt}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{kamdomesta.png}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{-20pt}
  \caption{RegisterActivity}
  \vspace{-10pt}
\end{wrapfigure}
\subsection*{KamDoMesta}
Aplikácia poskytuje používateľom prehľad prebiehajúcich filmových predstavení, výstav, prednášok a pod. vo zvolenom meste v daný deň. Za výhody považujem jednoduché používateľské rozhranie, ktoré tvorí v hlavnej aktivite jeden ListView využívajúci knižnicu StickyHeader, ktorá pomáha rozdeliť záznamy do kategórií. Nevýhod je na druhej strane oveľa viac. Chýba vyhľadávanie podľa zadanej ulice, alebo mesta. V aplikácií sa síce dá zvoliť mesto, ale ich zoznam je celkom priemerný a obsahuje len zopár vybraných miest, dokonca pri spustení aplikácie sa stále zobrazujú výsledky pre mesto Košice. Tak isto chýbajú možnosti pre používateľom pre hodnotenie udalosti, resp. komentovanie, pričom webová verzia aplikácie ponúka pridávanie komentárov pomocou pluginov spoločnosti Facebook, ich zahrnutie do aplikácie by nebolo vôbec náročné.
\end{document}
```

[image]